# Connection to socket refused

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have simple TCP server program. After I close it with `CTRL+C` and restart again in some cases telnet client report me `"connection refused"`. Why it happens not always, but just in some cases? Command `ps` shows nothing regarding my programm.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printHex(char *bts);

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(22000);
    printf("binding\n");
    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    printf("listening\n");
    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    printf("accepting\n");    
    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
    printf("accep done\n");

    int cn = 0;

    while(1) {
        bzero(str, 100);
        printf("will read\n");
        int br = read(comm_fd, str, 100);
        printf("read done\n");
        if (br > 0) {
            printHex(str);
        } else if (br <= 0) {
            comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
            printf("accep done\n");
        }
        printf("error %d \n", br);
   }
}

void printHex(char *bts) {
    char *s = bts;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned char) *bts);
    } while (*++bts !=0);
    printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

Comment: there's no error checking in your code. Maybe that would be a start?

Comment: To add to what @Roddy stated: how do you know your calls to `bind()` or `listen()` worked?

Comment: OT: "*`do ... while (*++bts !=0);`*": you cannot rely on `read()` reading  a `0`, at least not as long the client does not *only* sends `0`s. Calling `read()` on a socket may return any number of bytes between 1 and the maximum specified by the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Close the open sockets, cleanup is essential. Catch the interrupt to do so.

Comment: @Erobrere: Which "*interrupt*"?

Comment: Interrupt for `Ctrl+C`

Comment: @alk read may return 0 if this is end of file, in case of TCP if other side closes connection

Comment: @tinky_winky: "*read may return 0 if ...*" I know. And I wasn't referring to read *returning* `0` but to `read()` not necessarily *reading* any `0` *into the buffer* provided.

Comment: @Erobrere do you have to free all the memory you allocated too?

Comment: You should `close` the socket before you `accept` another connection however.

Comment: @Erobrere: Sockets (as well as any other open file descriptors) get closed automagically by the OS (at least on Linux) when the process ends.

Comment: Adding to @alk 's comment; `printHex` should take a byte count argument to tell it how many bytes to dump instead of relying on a zero terminator in the buffer.

Comment: @alk Yes I'm aware of that. I mentioned it in the context of best practices to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check all return values from system calls:

```
int res;

res = bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
if (res == -1)
  // handle error
listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (listed_fd == -1)
  // handle error
```

Most likely you will find then that your code fails on a `bind` system call, which means you can't reuse socket on same IP address, protocol and port. You can change this using `setsockopt` call:

```
// allow to rebind
int reuseaddr_on = 1;
res = setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
            &reuseaddr_on, sizeof(reuseaddr_on));              
if (res < 0)
{
    stderr("Setting of SO_REUSEADDR on server's"     
                            "socket failed");                         
}
```

You should also close a socket when you are done with it.

```
while(1)
{
  //  your loop
}
res = close(comm_fd);
if (res == -1)
  // handle error
```

As Linux Programmer's Manual says on pages devoted to close call:

> NOTES
>
> Not  checking the return value of close() is a common but nevertheless serious programming error.  It is quite possible that
>   errors on a previous write(2) operation are first reported at the final close().  Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to silent
>   loss of
>          data.

Comment: @downvoter could you please explain your downvote? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the return values of your syscalls.
In this case,

```
    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

fails with `EADDRINUSE`, because you didn't set `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket before binding.

Answer (score 0):

When you do CTRL-C and restart again, is the bind sucessful?

`bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));`

You need to check the status of the `bind call`. In all likelihood, this has failed due to connection having moved to `TIME_WAIT` state in server. And from this follows the error "connection refused" in client.

Far the `bind` to be successful when the server is run immediately after `CTRL-C`, use the `SO_REUSEADDR` in your socket option. With this `bind` will be successful, as long as there isn't another program bound to the port.